# Trigger when new row added

Tags: sql-server, triggers, alert

I'm looking to have a trigger show when a new row is added to my Vendor table. The query I've written so far is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tVendorAdded
ON Vendors
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AlertTable
       SELECT  
           VendorID, VendorName, GETDATE(),
           'Vendor Added', 'New vendor, ' + VendorName + ', added'
       FROM 
           inserted
       WHERE --
END
GO
```

What do I add to my where clause to get this to happen? Is there something different/better that I should try instead?

Comment: *When a new row is added* -----> this would be an `INSERT` operation - not an `UPDATE` !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tVendorAdded ON Vendors
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AlertTable (VendorId, VendorName, ?, ?, ?)
        SELECT VendorID, VendorName, getdate(), 'Vendor Added',
              'New vendor, ' + VendorName + ', added'
        FROM inserted;
END;
```

You should include the column names in the `INSERT` statement.  The `?` is for the names of the appropriate columns.

Comment: It hasn't triggered or added anything when I entered a new row in Vendor as a test. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ShreddedSaber . . . This is an after *UPDATE* trigger.  If you want something entered after an *insert*, then you need an `after insert` trigger.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!